# Clicking images to pass the names in a URL string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a low level knowledge of javascript and am trying to create a basic image based quiz that passes data back to a search page for local businesses.

Each image would have it's own "tag" as the image ID that relates to one of the options in the search. Ie. Outdoor, Ballroom, Barn, Garden, etc.

Upon submission, it would send the selected image ID's  data to www.sitename/search/?_characteristics=TAG1,TAG2,TAG3

That search page will filter the business listings by the tags. Currently it's search function filters the businesses with the following format: website.com/search/?_characteristics=TAG1%2CTAG2

The HTML would look like this:

```html
<img src="http://website.com/image1" id="TAG1"/>
    <br/>
 <img src="http://website.com/image2" id="TAG2"/>
    
<form action="https://website.com/business/?&_characteristics=TAG1, TAG2, TAG3" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="View Selected"/>
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Where do the _tags_ come from? When should they be added to the URL and when and how is the request sent to the server?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am trying to understand what you want to achieve but I don't know if I completely understand what you are saying. Are you talking about an `AJAX` or `HTTP` call with "send the data to"?

Comment: @Phil I updated the post to be a bit more clear. The tags are attributes on the business pages that the search page will filter. I'm looking to have users click images that correspond to those attributes, such as a restaurant with outdoor seating, business with wifi, or venue with air-conditioning. Those tags will be the image ID's that would then be passed via URL to the search page.

Comment: You haven't addressed my comments on the timing. Also, what happens if an image is clicked multiple times? How are users meant to know if an image is _selected_ or not?

Comment: @Phil For timing, when the user clicks submit, it would encode the URL string and take them to the search page. For the images being selected, it would change the class of the image to be outlined. If they click it again, it would be unselected and return to the default state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the following

1. Register a click handler on your images to

   1. Capture ids into a collection (array or Set)
   2. Toggle the *"selected"* class
2. Register a submit handler on the form to inject an hidden input element, transforming the *tag* collection into a CSV and setting it to the input value

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form")
const tags = new Set()

document.querySelectorAll("img[id]").forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const selected = img.classList.toggle("selected")
    tags[selected ? "add" : "delete"](img.id)
  })
})

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  const input = Object.assign(document.createElement("input"), {
    name: "_characteristics",
    type: "hidden",
    value: ([...tags]).join(",")    
  })
  
  form.append(input)

  // this is just for the example, omit the following
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(`Submitting to ${form.action}?${new URLSearchParams(new FormData(form))}`)
  input.remove()
})
```

```css
img { border: 2px solid grey; }
img.selected { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/100" id="TAG1"/>
<br/>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/100" id="TAG2"/>
    
<form action="https://website.com/business/" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="View Selected"/>
</form>
```

Comment: This worked great - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to get the selected `img`, but here's a way to do it:

1. Add the class `active` to the selected `img`
2. When clicking on the `button`, get the `id` and push it to the `output` array
3. Create the *link* of the tags (`id`'s)

Read the comments below for the detailed explanation.

```js
// Get the images and the submit button
let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
// Array to hold the tags
let output = [];
// variable to hold the link
let link = '';

// Add the class active to the selected images
for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  // For each image onclick:
  images[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Toggle the `active` class on click
    images[i].classList.toggle('active');
  });
}

// Button onclick:
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    // Get the images with the `active` class and push the id to the output array 
    images[i].classList.contains('active') ? output.push(images[i].getAttribute('id')) : '';
  }
  
  // Remove duplicates if found
  let uniq = [...new Set(output)];
  
  // Create the link by adding the tags to the string (output values)
  link = `www.sitename/search/?_characteristics=${uniq.join(',')}`;
  
  // Print the link to the console
  console.log(link);
});
```

```css
img.active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #121212;
}
```

```html
5. <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" id="air-conditioned"/>
<br/>

6. <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" id="outdoor"/>
<br/>

7. <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" id="indoor"/>
<br/>

8. <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" id="house"/>
<br/>

<button id="btn">Submit</button>
```